# C# and Xpath - return result using Node-Set and string type result in single Xpath query

Tags: c#, html, xpath, scrape

In project I am using Xpath to scrape price. In that case I can have 2 options how to get price specified with next query:

```
var xpath = @"substring-after(//div[@class='price'],":")|//span[@class="oldPrice"]";
```

In C# code:

```
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.DocumentNode.CreateNavigator();
            var eval = navigator.Evaluate(xpath); // here i get error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
            var expression = navigator.Compile(xpath); // and also here i get error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
```

I understand that `substring-after(//div[@class='price'],":")` is return type of string.
and that `//span[@class="oldPrice"]` is return type of Node-Set

Do you have suggestion how should I take that case?  
 a) Should I split xpath and resolve each part separated by '|' ? 
b) Or is there other way to get result using combined xpath query above without spliting string and checking each part? 
 c) Did I miss any other class that does what I am looking for?

I hope there is enough context.

Answer (score 0):

The union operator only works on node-sets, so your expression should fail because the LHS is a string (it's a string even if the //div selects nothing).

Are you expecting `//span[@class="oldPrice"]` to return a single node? In that case, you could convert it to a string using the string() function, and then concatenate the two strings using the concat() function.

Consider moving to a later version of XPath, which allows you to return sequences of strings.